# How can I have different column arrangement and different card designs for my index in bootstrap?

Tags: css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'm doing a crud website using bootstrap and laravel. I need some help in doing design and layout. I'm showing my assets at the index page using a foreach, but I'd like to show it as 3 large cards with full details on the first full column, and 5 small card with less details on the second column.

How should I proceed? Thank you.

EDIT: Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eacb.jpg). What I currently have is like the first column. Can I do this inside only one foreach so that it's dynamic and every new asset added will display on the 3 large cards?

```
@foreach ($games as $game)
    <div class="col-4 mt-3 d-flex align-items-stretch">
        <div class="card landing-card">

            <img src='{{ asset("storage/$game->image_location") }}' class="img-fluid">

            <div class="card-body landing-card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title landing-card-title">{{ $game->title }}</h4>

                <p class="card-text landing-card-text">Summary: {{ $game->description }}</p>
                <p class="card-text landing-card-text">Genre: {{ $game->genre->name }}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="card-footer landing-card-footer btn-group btn-block">
                <form action='{{ url("/pending/$game->id/index" )}}'class="form-add-to-cart" data-id="{{ $game->id }}">
                    <div class="btn-group btn-block">
                        <button class="btn landing-card-button peach-gradient">Submit Request</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "3 large cards with full details on the first full column, and 5 small card with less details on the second column". Can you post a simple wireframe or draft showing that? Also, can you post a screenshot of what you currently have?

Comment: Hi there. I've edited my post with a link. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @rwantstocode, have you seen my answer? If that's helpful, I would appreciate if you could accept it is the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Grid System

### Bootstrap Grid System

The first thing to know is: Bootstrap Grid system uses **12 columns** by default. Usually, we try to match that in our designs. For example:

- **3 Cards**: Each card takes **4 columns**
- **2 Cards**: Each card takes **6 columns**
- **5 Cards**: Each card takes **2.4 columns...** Oops! Not an exact number!

That's why in the screenshot you posted, you can see a little gap in each side of the second row. A row with 5 cards doesn't match the top row with 3 cards. So you could have that same design with a second row like this:

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-1'><!-- This is just a space to help the math --></div>
  <div class='col-2'>Card 1</div>
  <div class='col-2'>Card 2</div>
  <div class='col-2'>Card 3</div>
  <div class='col-2'>Card 4</div>
  <div class='col-2'>Card 5</div>
  <div class='col-1'><!-- This is just a space to help the math --></div>
</div>
```

*See how the sum of the columns is 12?*

That's until Flexbox...

#### Flexbox

Bootstrap 4 uses Flexbox, which is more flexible. It stills simulates the 12 columns grid, so you can't use Bootstrap default classes (e.g.: `col-2`) to achieve the 5 cards layout. But you can create your own class, using a `flex-basis: 20%` (100% / 5 = 20%).

---

## Finally, your solution

### Using one loop

To use one loop, you could use `$loop->index` to check if you are rendering the first 3 cards or the other ones. This may become a bit messy, depending on how many "games" you have on your data. And you need to use `Flexbox` for this:

```
@foreach ($games as $game)
  @if($loop->index < 3) 
    <div class="col-4 mt-3 d-flex align-items-stretch">
        <div class="card landing-card">
            <img src='{{ asset("storage/$game->image_location") }}' class="img-fluid">
            <div class="card-body landing-card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title landing-card-title">{{ $game->title }}</h4>
                <p class="card-text landing-card-text">Summary: {{ $game->description }}</p>
                <p class="card-text landing-card-text">Genre: {{ $game->genre->name }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer landing-card-footer btn-group btn-block">
                <form action='{{ url("/pending/$game->id/index" )}}'class="form-add-to-cart" data-id="{{ $game->id }}">
                    <div class="btn-group btn-block">
                        <button class="btn landing-card-button peach-gradient">Submit Request</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  @else
    <div class="my-flex-class-with-20%">
      <img src='{{ asset("storage/$game->image_location") }}' class="img-fluid">
    </div>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

### Using multiple loops

By using multiple loops, you could either achieve the same layout you posted, or different ones. You would need to split your `$games` variable into two arrays. One with the first 3 "games" and the other with the rest of the games.

Your loop in the first array would be similar to what you already have, and your loop in the second array would change the CSS classes. Ideally, your second array would be an array of arrays, each containing the amount of games you want. That would allow you to insert a proper `row` every time, which is good for your CSS.

Something like this:

```
// Top row:
<div class='row'>
  @foreach ($first_3_games as $game)
    <div class="col-4">
      Your content here
    </div>
  @endforeach
</div>

// $other_games = [[game1, game2, game3, game4, game5], [game6, game7, game8, game9, game10]]

// This replicates the layout on your question:
@foreach ($other_games as $game_list)
  <div class='row'>
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    @foreach ($game_list as $game)
      <div class="col-2">
        Your content here
      </div>
    @endforeach
    <div class="col-1"></div>
  </div>
@endforeach

// This takes the whole space to match the top row with 3 games
@foreach ($other_games as $game_list)
  <div class='row'>
    @foreach ($game_list as $game)
      <div class="custom-flex-basis-20%-class">
        Your content here
      </div>
    @endforeach
  </div>
@endforeach
```

---

PS.: Just a little clarification on your question: you want 3 items in the first **row**, not **column**. Row is horizontal, column is vertical